# Apache2 virtual host not working on macOS

Tags: macos, apache, virtualhost

Trying to set up apache2 virtual hosts on macOS Big Sur using Homebrew. When I go to 127.0.0.1 in the browser it gets the correct website (A basic HTML file), but when I try to access with the server name `http://ms-dashboard.harry.milestone.barn/` it says site can't be reached.

Important stuff from httpd.conf

```
Listen 80
ServerName harry.milestone.barn
Include /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/harry/Sites/MS-Dashboard/public"
    ServerName ms-dashboard.harry.milestone.barn
    ErrorLog "/Users/harry/Sites/MS-Dashboard/logs/error_log"
    CustomLog "/Users/harry/Sites/MS-Dashboard/logs/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost harry.milestone.barn ms-dashboard.harry.milestone.barn
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Error log when 127.0.0.1 accessed

```
[Wed Jun 01 10:25:39.133465 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 1219] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 127.0.0.1:63629] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Wed Jun 01 10:25:39.133898 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 1219] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 127.0.0.1:63629] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Wed Jun 01 10:25:59.133782 2022] [reqtimeout:info] [pid 1220] [client 127.0.0.1:63630] AH01382: Request header read timeout
```

Access Log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jun/2022:10:25:39 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jun/2022:10:25:59 +0100] "-" 408 -
```

The logs are not changed when ms-dashboard.harry.milestone.barn is accessed.

I've looked at a million different StackOverflow questions about the same thing and none of their solutions work.

Comment: What is in your `/Users/harry/Sites/MS-Dashboard/logs/error_log` and `/Users/harry/Sites/MS-Dashboard/logs/access_log`? Check if apache is actually listening your `:80` port

Comment: I've added the logs to the question

Answer (score 1):

Solved: there are two hosts files, I was editing the wrong one